# Script to extract unique lists from text file in powershell

Tags: powershell, unique

I have a text file with content similar to this:

```
abc = 000
abc = 000
abc = 000
abc = xxx

abc = 111
abc = 111
abc = 111
abc = xxx

abc = 000
abc = 000
abc = 000
abc = xxx

abc = 222
abc = 222
abc = 222
abc = xxx

abc = 000
abc = 000
abc = 000
abc = xxx
```

It can happen that the lists are identical and appear often in the file (like the tripple zero one). Now I need a script to extract only the unique lists and write them to a new file. In this example it should look like this:

```
abc = 000
abc = 000
abc = 000
abc = xxx

abc = 111
abc = 111
abc = 111
abc = xxx

abc = 222
abc = 222
abc = 222
abc = xxx
```

Until now I tried the following in powershell:

```
gc -delimiter "xxx" file |select -unique > newfile
```

Unfortunately this won't work correctly. How to solve this?

Comment: Are all the lists exactly 4 items?

Comment: yes, they are all exactly 4 items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work with your test data:

```
((gc test.txt -ReadCount 5 |
foreach {($_ -match '\S')| out-string}) |
select -unique) -Join "`n"
```